# wasserstein_distance for multidimesional data

Tags: python, scipy, scipy.stats

I am trying to compute the wasserstein distance for two point clouds and I have written the following below code my doubt is that my original point clouds are in 3D and to align with the library that I am using I flatten the data is it okay?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import wasserstein_distance
from plyfile import PlyData

def load_point_cloud(file_name):
    plydata = PlyData.read(file_name)
    points = np.array([list(x) for x in plydata['vertex'].data])
    return points

def compute_wasserstein_distance(cloud1, cloud2):
    # Flatten the point clouds to 1D arrays (assuming 3D points)
    u_values = cloud1.flatten()
    v_values = cloud2.flatten()

    # Compute Wasserstein distance
    distance = wasserstein_distance(u_values, v_values)
    return distance

# Load point clouds
cloud1 = load_point_cloud('/home/amit/bunny.ply')
cloud2 = load_point_cloud('/home/amit/Datasets/Animal Dataset/dragon.ply')

# Compute Wasserstein distance
distance = compute_wasserstein_distance(cloud1, cloud2)
print(f"Wasserstein Distance: {distance}")
```

I am confused that if flatting the data changes the geometry of the original point cloud or not? If yes then is there any way to compute it in my case?

Comment: Have you tried your code with, say, 5 points and checked (by hand) if the results are correct? If not, I recommend you add those points to your question (we don't have access to the CSV files you're working with) and show the current output along with the desired output (and explain why the desired output is correct).

Comment: for the above two point clouds I am getting the following:
0.1116

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly not true that flattening the data preserves the Wasserstein distance.

Imagine each cloud has exactly one point, say <1, 2, 3> and <2, 3, 1>.

The Wasserstein difference between these two points is non-zero, while the distance between [2, 3, 1] and [1, 2, 3] is zero.

Comment: so is there any way to do it?

Comment: @tiger you may try Python optimal transport package, https://pythonot.github.io/gen_modules/ot.lp.html#id17. Something like EarthMoverDistance emd2d might work?